# Why use FileUtils.forceMkdir?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

What is the use of `FileUtils.forceMkdir` from Apache commons-io instead of `File.mkdirs` built into the JRE?

The docs to `forceMkdir` are

> Makes a directory, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. If a file already exists with specified name but it is not a directory then an IOException is thrown. If the directory cannot be created (or does not already exist) then an IOException is thrown.

While the docs to `mkdirs` are

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

Is the only difference in the type of exception thrown?

Comment: Notice `Path` is a newer and more general class for `File`. See [`Files.createDirectories`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) which does the same. Use the JRE version, `Files`.

Comment: @JoopEggen is there some technical reason that I would want to use the `Files` implementation instead of `File`?

Comment: It is newer code, and just as you would use List instead of ArrayList a Path can be a file inside a zip (a zip file system, with URI jar:file:/...). There are some slight differences between new and old style functions, but it shoud not matter here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the main difference is that implementation from Apache commons is "louder": it will throw exception if the directory to create already exist, but it is actually a file. Looks like the idea was to wrap the JRE implementation that returns `false` instead of exception in case of unsuccessful directory creation.